# Duplicating the condition gives a different result set

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation_member t82
WHERE (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level + '1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
) AND (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level+'1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
)
```

As you can see, the two conditions are identical, so if I removed one of the conditions, the query should give the same result. However, the query returns a different result when both of the conditions are there, than when using only one of them!

The inner query used in the conditions (below) returns `115,131,153` in my case.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
FROM (
   SELECT @Level := @Level+'1' `Level`, @Ids := (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
      FROM dp_organisation
      WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
   ) `Ids`
   FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
   INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
) temp2
```

When both conditions are used, the result only includes the rows having `OrganisationId = 1`. When only one of the conditions is used, also the rows having `OrganisationId` equal to `115`, `131`, or `153` are included.

So the query below produce the correct result:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation_member t82
WHERE (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level + '1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
)
```

Also if I substitute one of the inner queries with the result of that query, the query gives the correct result:

```
SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation_member t82
WHERE (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, "115,131,153")
) AND (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level+'1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
)
```

The first query in this question, having the duplicated condition, however, does not give the correct result.

Can anyone give an explanation for this behavior?

**Edit**

I think it might be a problem with MariaDB. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9aa8bd/1) with MySQL, giving the correct result. It doesn't seem to be possible to use MariaDB in SQL Fiddle. Is there any other easy way to test queries in MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with newer versions of MySQL and MariaDB.

I experience the issue in these databases:

- MySQL 5.7.17
- MariaDB 10.1.25

But it works fine in these databases:

- MySQL 5.6.35
- MySQL 5.5.51

To test your database for the issue, perform the following queries. The final query should return 4 rows. If it returns only one row, your database version is affected by the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_organisation` (
  `OrganisationId` bigint(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ParentId` bigint(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrganisationId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=154 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `dp_organisation_member` (
  `OrganisationId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrganisationId`,`UserId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `dp_organisation` VALUES (1,NULL),(2,NULL),(3,2),(115,1),(131,1),(153,115);

INSERT INTO `dp_organisation_member` VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(115,4),(131,5),(153,6);


SELECT *
FROM dp_organisation_member t82
WHERE (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level + '1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
) AND (
   t82.`OrganisationId` = '1' OR FIND_IN_SET(t82.`OrganisationId`, (
      SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`Ids`)
      FROM (
         SELECT @Level := @Level+'1' `Level`, @Ids := (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`OrganisationId`)
            FROM dp_organisation
            WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`ParentId`, @Ids)
         ) `Ids`
         FROM (SELECT @Ids := '1', @Level := '0') temp1
         INNER JOIN dp_organisation ON NOT(ISNULL(@Ids))
      ) temp2
   ))
)
```

**Edit**

The bug has been verified by MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87339

**Edit 2018-10-30**
Here is a fiddle for testing it. The issue is also present in MySQL 8.0.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5SAJZJosQXMZsDmU1Lmi8X/0